# How to get full document from mongoDB with FindOne() function from the official MongoDB Go driver

Tags: mongodb, go

I am trying to get a single document from **MongoDB** and Decode it into a struct that contains slice. 
I use the **official MongoDB Go driver**.

I've tried **collection.FindOne()**, that returns everything but slices, and **collection.Find()** that returns EOF.

Here's a simple FindOne() function:

```
func FindOne(c *mongo.Collection, filter, result interface{}, opts ...*options.FindOneOptions) error {

    err := c.FindOne(context.TODO(), filter, opts...).Decode(result)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

I'm trying to decode result into structs:

```
type UserBonus struct {
    Id                   string          `protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=id,proto3" json:"id,omitempty"`
    User                 *User           `protobuf:"bytes,2,opt,name=user,proto3" json:"user,omitempty"`
    Bonus                []*Bonus        `protobuf:"bytes,3,rep,name=bonus,proto3" json:"bonus,omitempty"`
    Payments             []*BonusPayment `protobuf:"bytes,4,rep,name=payments,proto3" json:"payments,omitempty"`
}

type Bonus struct {
    Id                   string   `protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=id,proto3" json:"id,omitempty"`
    DueDate              int64    `protobuf:"varint,2,opt,name=dueDate,proto3" json:"dueDate,omitempty"`
    CancelDate           int64    `protobuf:"varint,3,opt,name=cancelDate,proto3" json:"cancelDate,omitempty"`
    LastUpdate           int64    `protobuf:"varint,4,opt,name=lastUpdate,proto3" json:"lastUpdate,omitempty"`
    Amount               float32  `protobuf:"fixed32,5,opt,name=amount,proto3" json:"amount,omitempty"`
}

type BonusPayment struct {
    Id                   string   `protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=id,proto3" json:"id,omitempty"`
    ProductId            int64    `protobuf:"varint,2,opt,name=productId,proto3" json:"productId,omitempty"`
    Amount               float32  `protobuf:"fixed32,3,opt,name=amount,proto3" json:"amount,omitempty"`
    CreateDate           int64    `protobuf:"varint,4,opt,name=createDate,proto3" json:"createDate,omitempty"`
    CancelDate           int64    `protobuf:"varint,5,opt,name=cancelDate,proto3" json:"cancelDate,omitempty"`
    LastUpdate           int64    `protobuf:"varint,6,opt,name=lastUpdate,proto3" json:"lastUpdate,omitempty"`
}
```

```
col := mng.GetCollection(db, "bonus")
filter := bson.M{"id":"duma@mail.com"}

var result pb.UserBonus

err = mng.FindOne(col, filter, &result)
```

But the result is

```
{"id":"duma@mail.com","user":{"id":"duma@mail.com","firstName":"Comte","lastName":"de La Fère","email":"duma@mail.com"}}
```

without 
**[]*Bonus**
and 
**[]*BonusPayment**,
but if I open terminal it shows me full result

```
db.bonus.findOne({"id":"duma@mail.com"})
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d030aadf464d3397c73ec32"),
    "id" : "duma@mail.com",
    "user" : {
        "id" : "duma@mail.com",
        "firstname" : "Comte",
        "lastname" : "de La Fère",
        "email" : "duma@mail.com",
        "balance" : 134.5999984741211
    },
    "bonus" : [
        {
            "id" : "",
            "duedate" : NumberLong(1560480429),
            "canceldate" : NumberLong(0),
            "lastupdate" : NumberLong(1560480429),
            "amount" : 50
        },
        {
            "createDate" : NumberLong(1560480429),
            "lastUpdate" : NumberLong(1560480429),
            "amount" : 34.5
        }
    ],
    "lastbonusid" : NumberLong(0),
    "payments" : [
        {
            "id" : "",
            "productid" : NumberLong(1),
            "amount" : 10,
            "createdate" : NumberLong(0),
            "canceldate" : NumberLong(0),
            "lastupdate" : NumberLong(0)
        }
    ]
}
```

---

**Found the issue.**
If I after inserting I run update query

```
update := bson.M{
            "$inc": bson.M{"user.balance": input.Bonus.Amount},
    }
```

It stops bringing arrays and user.balance, but it's a different issue.
Thanks, everybody who tried to help.

Comment: Can you add the output of the CLI command to your question by [editing it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56590927/edit)?

Comment: Please also add type definitions for Bonus and BonusPayment.

Answer (score 0):

i have some project using the old community driver (mgo), and i faced this problem. My solution was to add a tag 'bson' in my Struct's Fields.

```
type UserBonus struct {
    Id                   string          `protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=id,proto3" json:"id,omitempty"`
    User                 *User           `protobuf:"bytes,2,opt,name=user,proto3" json:"user,omitempty"`
    Bonus                []*Bonus        `protobuf:"bytes,3,rep,name=bonus,proto3" json:"bonus,omitempty" bson:"bonus,omitempty"`
    Payments             []*BonusPayment `protobuf:"bytes,4,rep,name=payments,proto3" json:"payments,omitempty" bson:"payments,omitempty"`
}

type Bonus struct {
    Id                   string   `protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=id,proto3" json:"id,omitempty"`
    DueDate              int64    `protobuf:"varint,2,opt,name=dueDate,proto3" json:"dueDate,omitempty"`
    CancelDate           int64    `protobuf:"varint,3,opt,name=cancelDate,proto3" json:"cancelDate,omitempty"`
    LastUpdate           int64    `protobuf:"varint,4,opt,name=lastUpdate,proto3" json:"lastUpdate,omitempty"`
    Amount               float32  `protobuf:"fixed32,5,opt,name=amount,proto3" json:"amount,omitempty"`
}

type BonusPayment struct {
    Id                   string   `protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=id,proto3" json:"id,omitempty"`
    ProductId            int64    `protobuf:"varint,2,opt,name=productId,proto3" json:"productId,omitempty"`
    Amount               float32  `protobuf:"fixed32,3,opt,name=amount,proto3" json:"amount,omitempty"`
    CreateDate           int64    `protobuf:"varint,4,opt,name=createDate,proto3" json:"createDate,omitempty"`
    CancelDate           int64    `protobuf:"varint,5,opt,name=cancelDate,proto3" json:"cancelDate,omitempty"`
    LastUpdate           int64    `protobuf:"varint,6,opt,name=lastUpdate,proto3" json:"lastUpdate,omitempty"`
}
```

Give it a try and let me know if works.

Comment: It brings empty values now:
```{
  "id": "duma@mail.com",
  "user": {
    "id": "duma@mail.com",
    "firstName": "Comte",
    "lastName": "de La Fère",
    "email": "duma@mail.com"
  },
  "bonus": null,
  "payments": null
}```
Tried to put arrays inside User stract but it's the same:
```{
  "id": "duma@mail.com",
  "user": {
    "id": "duma@mail.com",
    "firstName": "Comte",
    "lastName": "de La Fère",
    "email": "duma@mail.com",
    "bonus": null,
    "payments": null
  }
}```